# how to find user creation date along with all permissions in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I am trying to find users I have created in postgresql with date and time stamp along with permissions assigned to them. I have searched few tables like pg_user but couldn't find it.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Questions like that come up frequently, usually asking for the table creation time, so I'll try to answer that for good.

PostgreSQL does not track the creation time of objects or other auditing information like that in the database. Even if we considered such a feature, it would be questionable how that should work. If you restore a `pg_dump`, would the creation time of a table or role be the time of the restore? If not, there would have to be a way to override the table or role creation time in SQL. But then you cannot prevent people from dropping an object and creating it again with a fake old creation timestamp.

The correct way to approach such a requirement is the log file. Set `log_statement = 'ddl'` and all DDL statements will get logged.

Answer (score 0):

2 steps to resolve this

1. Make sure track_commit_timestamp is on

```
show track_commit_timestamp ;
track_commit_timestamp
------------------------
 on
```

(1 row)

2. Execute

```
select pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xmin) from pg_authid;
```